# How to hide column in excel report generated by JasperReports?

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to hide some columns in the excel report for my future reference. 
Please suggest me any idea to hide the column.

Comment: Try to use [net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.hidden](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.hidden)

Comment: Doesn't work. According to the "JasperReports - Configuration Reference (version 6.21.0)" the property net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.hidden is used to specify if the cell content is hidden or exposed in the formula bar of a protected sheet. The original question was for hiding column and this property only hides content in the formula bar under specific circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex K's comment is correct. Here's how to apply it:

1. Open the **Source** page for the report to view the XML.
2. Find the field to hide in Excel.
3. Add the property to the `reportElement` as follows:

```xml
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.hidden" value="true"/>
</reportElement>
```

The `reportElement` attribute values will differ in the report you create.

Comment: Alex K and Dave Jarvis are not correct.
According to the ["JasperReports - Configuration Reference (version 6.21.0)"](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.hidden) the property net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.cell.hidden is used to specify if the cell content is hidden or exposed in the formula bar of a protected sheet. The original question was for hiding column and this property only hides content in the formula bar under specific circumstances.

Comment: Did you try using the `cell.hidden` property, @zellers? What happened when you did?

Comment: Yes I did and the result was as predicted by the documentation. Formula was hidden in a locked sheet but column / row was still visible. @dave-jarvis [Your move.](https://imgur.com/a/Cd34Lst)